# Tried callback vs promise_then vs async_await and found that callback is fastest - is it true?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, callback

I was trying to compare between Node.js `callback` vs `promise_then` vs `async_await` and found that `callback` is the fastest. Is it true? Not sure if I am approaching this correctly.

I have created an `add` function for all three `callback`, `promise_then` and `async_await`. When the following code was ran in node and results printed out as  `console.log`, `callback` was printed first, followed by `promise_then` and finally `async_await` even though I have arranged the function calls such that `callback` gets called last.

```
// promise_then
const add_promise = (a, b) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(a + b)
    })
}

// async_await
const add_async_await = async() => {
    const sum = await add_promise(1, 99)
    const sum2 = await add_promise(sum, 50)
    const sum3 = await add_promise(sum2, 3)
    return sum3
}

// callback
function add_callback(a, b, callback) {
    callback(a + b)
}

add_async_await().then((result) => {
    console.log('result await', result) // await third fastest (3)??
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('e', e)
})

add_promise(1,99).then((sum) => {
    add_promise(sum, 50).then((sum2) => {
        add_promise(sum2, 3).then((sum3) => {
            console.log('result promise', sum3) // promise second fastest (2)??
        })
    })
})

add_callback(1, 99, function(sum) {
    add_callback(sum, 50, function(sum2) {
        add_callback(sum2, 3, function(sum3) {
            console.log('result callback', sum3) // callback fastest (1)??
        })
    })
})
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
result callback 153
result promise 153
result await 153
```

Given the order of the output, does this mean that `callback` is fastest, followed by `promise` and finally `await`? Or maybe the ordering of `console.log` does not matter?

Comment: You're doing a synchronous callback.  That isn't really a fair comparison as communicating back an asynchronous result via callback will always involve some asynchronous operation.  You should benchmark communicating back an asycnhronous result, not comparing a promise with a synchronous callback.  That's not a valid comparison.  By definition, a promise lets the stack unwind first (potentially executing other code first) before calling it's `.then()` handler so it will always lose to a synchronous callback.  But, synchronous callback isn't an option with a real asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider some points then you understand.

1. callbacks which can be either asynchronous or synchronous.Here may be you are using synchronous callback.
2. If you have an async event that only finishes once (e.g. ajax call) over callbacks then promises are much better than callbacks, because they are much easier to compose